# require() a custom package?

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity, require

I am trying to install an npm package from a custom registry through npm, in a project's build step, in TeamCity.

I create a build step with the following settings:

**Runner type:** Command Line

**Step name:** Install

**Run:** Executable with parameters

**Command executable:** npm

**Command parameters:** install

And have specified the custom registry in the `.npmrc` file:

```
registry=http://...
```

But, When I start the build, I get this error:

> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
>   "install"
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! node v6.6.0 [16:29:20] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! code E404
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! 404 Not found : @mohito/libsvc
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! 404
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! 404  '@mohito/libsvc' is not in the npm registry. 
>   [16:29:20]    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or
>   use the name yourself!)
>
> [16:29:20]    npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of
>   'm-api-server' [16:29:20] npm ERR! 404
>
> ...
>
> Process exited with code 1

Why is npm not able to locate my `@mohito/libsvc` custom package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling TeamCity somehow made it work